# TinyMCE on Rails 4, the asset pipeline isn't flowing for me

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tinymce, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the tiny_mce folder inside of vendor/assets/javascripts/. In my application.js file, I have:

```
//= require tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js
```

In development, the Tiny mce editor works. In production on heroku it does not.

```
TypeError: this.getDoc(...) is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

... get source for: http://www.example.com/assets/application-fcf26d0749f321ac7...

applic...2815.js (line 31035)

Failed to load: http://www.example.com/entries/1//themes/advanced/editor_template.js

applic...2815.js (line 27236)

Failed to load: http://www.example.com/entries/1//langs/en.js
```

Here is the tiny_mce specific code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  document_base_url : "http://www.example.com/",
  mode : "textareas"
});
```

I think the issues are arising because of these double slashes:

```
Failed to load: http://www.example.com/entries/1//themes/advanced/editor_template.js
Failed to load: http://www.example.com/entries/1//langs/en.js
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After further debugging, I found that it was an assets problem. I fixed the issue by add this into the file in config/enviroments/production.rb.

```
config.assets.digest = false

# Add to settle tinymce issue
config.assets.debug = true
```